# ListBox does not update entries automaticly when using binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

Im having some trouble updating a listbox when new data is added to it. This is my code

The my listbox has

```
 <ListBox Name="EmailList" ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxData, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

And here is my program:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    string hostname = Properties.Settings.Default.pop_host;
    int port = Properties.Settings.Default.pop_port;
    bool useSsl = Properties.Settings.Default.pop_usessl;
    string username = "recent:" + Properties.Settings.Default.username;
    string password = Properties.Settings.Default.password;

        // When this button is pressed the program starts a backgroundworker
        // that begins the download of mails
    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker getNewMail = new BackgroundWorker();
        getNewMail.DoWork += newEmail;
        getNewMail.RunWorkerAsync();
        getNewMail.RunWorkerCompleted += updateList;
    }

    // The actual function that downloads the mails (Using OpenPOP)
    private void newEmail(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
    List<Message> allEmail = FetchAllMessages(hostname, port, useSsl, username, password);
            ListBoxData = new List<EmailEntry> { };

        foreach (Message singleEmail in allEmail)
        {
                var mailData = new ListBoxDataClass { theMessage = singleEmail, truncate = 40 };
                readyUpListBoxData(mailData);
                ListBoxData.Add(new EmailEntry { from = mailData.displayName, subject = mailData.partOfBody, messageID = singleEmail.Headers.MessageId.ToString() });   
        }
    }

    public class ListBoxDataClass
    {
        public Message theMessage { get; set; }
        public int truncate { get; set; }

        public string partOfBody { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
    }

    // A function that does different things with the downloaded data
    public void readyUpListBoxData(ListBoxDataClass data)
    {
        MessagePart theEmailTxt = data.theMessage.FindFirstPlainTextVersion();
        string noLineBreaks = theEmailTxt.GetBodyAsText().ToString().Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " ");
        data.partOfBody = noLineBreaks.Length <= data.truncate ? noLineBreaks : noLineBreaks.Substring(0, data.truncate) + " ..";
        data.displayName = data.theMessage.Headers.From.DisplayName.ToString();
        if (data.displayName == "")
        {
            data.displayName = data.theMessage.Headers.From.Address.ToString();
        }
        data.displayName += " <" + data.theMessage.Headers.From.Address.ToString() + ">";
    }
}
```

I believe im supposed to use something called observable collection or something like that? I just cannot see how i can use that here in my program. I hope that some of you guys can assist me in the usage of Observable collection or point me to something else i can use, that does what i need.

I was thinking about using something like timer to achieve it, but im not sure that it would be good practice ?

Comment: You would make a public observablecollection<YourClass> ListBoxData so xaml can access it

Comment: Despite @Tsukasa's terrible reasoning (*so xaml can access it*), that *is* the correct answer. Please take a look at the [ObservableCollection<T> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for more information.

Comment: @Sheridan SO should give you sheriff batch :)

Comment: Dude... there *is* a Sheriff badge, but it's a gold one and for having *Served as an elected moderator for at least 1 year*. Anyway, I'm not interested in such things... I just 'say it as I see it', so if someone has added a poor quality question or answer, you'd better believe that I'll tell them. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create public property for your ListBoxData as follows:

```
     public partial class MainWindow : Window
     {

         public ObservableCollection<EmailEntry > ListBoxData{get;set;}

         public MainWindow()
         {
             ListBoxData = new ObservableCollection<EmailEntry >();
             InitializeComponents();
         }

        private void newEmail(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
             List<Message> allEmail = FetchAllMessages(hostname, port, useSsl, username, password);


            foreach (Message singleEmail in allEmail)
            {
                var mailData = new ListBoxDataClass { theMessage = singleEmail, truncate = 40 };
                readyUpListBoxData(mailData);
                ListBoxData.Add(new EmailEntry { from = mailData.displayName, subject = mailData.partOfBody, messageID = singleEmail.Headers.MessageId.ToString() });   
            }
      }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can either implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and then raise `ListBoxData` property when you're done adding or just change your `ListBoxData` to `ObservableCollection` because it implements `INPC` by default.

Comment: -1 This has nothing to do with the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface... I believe that you are referring to the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface instead. We are talking about adding items, not changing property values.

Comment: @Sheridan What do you mean it has nothing to do with `INPC` it has. You can raise property change on each add on the `ListBox` to update it with the binding or like I said. Change it to `ObservableCollection`. Also, `ObservableCollection` implements `INPC` underneath with `INCC` so get your comments straight and I hope you know what you're talking about.

Comment: *get your comments straight*...  Wow, calm down... Why do you think that I wrote *I believe that you are referring to the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface instead*? Because the `ObservableCollection<T>` implements it of course... no other reason to mention it. So my comments *were* straight. *You can raise property change on each add on the ListBox*... really? What property name would you use when doing that? And why bother to do that at all when the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface does that for us? That's what it's for...

Comment: .. so, as I said, the `NotifyPropertyChanged` interface plays no part in this and is irrelevant to this problem. At the end of the day, you made a small mistake and we all do sometimes. You could have corrected it and I would have removed the down vote... but for some reason, you wanted a pointless argument instead. What's the point in that?

Comment: @Sheridan Yes it does play its part. Underneath the scenes the ObservableCollection calls `INPC` through `INCC` thus updating the `UI`. Implementing `INPC` on the Window and calling `OnPropertyChange` on the current implementation will update the entries after the `foreach` loop where he adds the items. My answer is both correct but of course he should just use `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: And no, I don't see where the small mistake I made was. I don't consider not saying that observablecollection implements `INCC` because the real thing WPF uses is the `INPC` not `INCC` and that is the real answer if you check how `ObservableCollection` works. Also, it's just not about changing property values. It is `updating the UI` does not work when adding items to the `List`.